# Graph API: User Access Token

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Graph API to get the feed of multiple public groups then that of multiple users.
When it comes to the feed of groups, it works flawlessly, all I have to do is fetch the following : 
**graph.facebook.com/$group_id/feed?limit={feedLimit}&access_token={access_token}**

My access token being comprised of: **AppID|AppSecret**

However when it comes to fetching the feed of a user (Whose confidentiality settings are set to public of course) all I get is an empty answer. I would've thought it impossible to get such info and stopped there but then I stumbled upon ApiGee. All I have to do then is authenticate as a user (facebook-Authenticated-user) and it works.

Here's an image of it: http://s9.postimg.org/ynq5tar9r/feed.jpg

My question is : "How is that possible? I've read all I could in the docs and I still can't understand how it works. And how can I remedy that?"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token you are using is an App token (AppId|AppSecret). With the app token you can't really get users personal feeds. With ApiGee you authenticated to get a user token, which can be used to fetch posts on the authenticated user's feed.

[Read more about Facebook's access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

Comment: Then how I do I get a user token? The doc isn't very explicit on that point.
That and and the collection of data I intend to create must be automated (to some extent at least) meaning is there a way to automate the getting of a user token? Using the PHP sdk for example?

Comment: You can get a user token by having the user authenticate with the application that you will be using to get the data. You can use the Javascript SDK, for example, to authenticate/login the user (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2). The user has to login with his password. Remember that you might need to have your app approved to be allowed to request certain permissions; you can do that in the Status & Review tab of your app's developer pages. Check out these articles on Facebook login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

Comment: With the PHP SDK you can use the manual login flow (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2). Many PHP packages/libs come with helper methods to simplify the flow. They include classes with methods like "getLoginUrl()" of the old PHP SDK.